# Writing an API for an iPad app for other apps to use - is this possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

I am hoping to create an iPad app to do the following:

> Download data from a user's machine/local server
>   Encrypt this data and store it securely on the iPad
>   Provide an API so that others can write specially signed apps that query this API to access the secure data.

Its is the last requirement I am starting to think is "impossible". Does anybody know whether it is possible or not and if not of any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share data between applications, a good solution is to create a custom clipoard type, and have both applications access it.

You can also write your data in a file, and ask iOS to open that file in another application. This other application will then open and decrypt the contents of this file.

Comment: The data is going to be sensitive and so storing it as a file that something else opens is not going to be a viable solution. Is there no way to communicate between apps at all then?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution other than creating a file or clipboard type. The latter may be read by other applications. You could also have a look at custom url schemes. Another problem is that the communication will work one way. I don't think you can have an application query another and get an answer.